# 은 in 할 줄은 몰랐죠 structure

Tags: grammar

I know it is not good to study grammar from songs. However, I am curious if this structure below is some kind of grammar.

7년을 만났죠 아무도 우리가 이렇게 쉽게 이별 **할 줄은 몰랐죠**

I know the structure "ㄹ 줄 모르다" but in this sentence why there is 은 here?
Hope someone can explain it. Thanks.

Link for the song lyric: [7년간의 사랑](https://kpopquote.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/lyric-7-years-of-love-kyuhyun-super-junior-hangul-romanization-english/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) 줄=depending noun (Its usage is similar to 것) : 줄 means way,
fact and situation.

그녀는 밥을 지을 줄 (=짓는 것을) 모른다.

She can not prepare dinner.

2) Here 은 is emphasis :

나는 법은 모른다. I do not know law (But I know a lot of other
 things)

큰 언니까지 날 속일 줄은 몰랐어

I can bear that everybody deceived me, but it is terrible that old sister deceived
 me.

Comment: Could you explain the depending noun? What does it really mean?

Comment: In english, it is corresponded to "thing". We  can not use a noun "thing" independently. For instance, beautifu thing. Here we need a adjective "beautiful". Similarly, we can not use 줄 independently. For example, 공부 할 줄=way of doing a study.

Comment: can you cite any link or material discussing about the dependent noun? I couldn't find any where saying that 줄 can be acted as a noun.

Comment: In the following site http://alldic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000237563&supid=kku000303822 it is 의존명사